# CsQuery to parse a collection of li items

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, csquery

Here's my code:

```
CQ dom = CQ.Create(htmlString);
var items = dom[".blog-accordion li"];

foreach (var li in items)
{
    var newTournament = false;
    var test = li["header h2"];
}
```

Inside the foreach loop `li` turns into a `IDomObject` variable and I can no longer drill down further into it.

Any suggestions? Here is the example HTML I'm trying to parse:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <header>
      <h2>Test</h2>
    </header>
  </li>
  <li>
    <header>
      <h2>Test 2</h2>
    </header>
  </li>
  <li>
    <header>
      <h2>Test 3</h2>
    </header>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to grab the text of each h2 element.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is done in order to keep `CsQuery` consistent with `jQuery` which behaves the same way. You can convert it back to a `CQ` object by calling the `.Cq()` method as such

```
foreach (var li in items)
{
    var newTournament = false;
    var test = li.Cq().Find("header h2");
}
```

Or if you'd like more `jQuery`ish syntax, the following also works:

```
foreach (var li in items)
{
    var newTournament = false;
    var test = CQ.Create(li)["header h2"];
}
```

Your code, could be re-factored to the following if you'd like:

```
var texts = CQ.Create(htmlString)[".blog-accordion li header h2"]
              .Select(x=>x.Cq().Text());
```

Comment: crikey i just edited your answer twice since I couldn't remember that Create() binds to a new dom. That's what a week off did to my old brain. `Cq()` creates a selection set from its argument, but still bound to the same DOM so you need to use `Find` to search within it, whereas `[..]` will select against the original DOM. `Create` always makes a new dom from its argument.

Comment: Thanks :) Glad to see you're back on you feet responding to pings. @Serg in case you don't know, Jamie is the guy who created and is developing CsQuery.